# How to set dependence between models in RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, dependencies

I have two models: User and Sensor. I want to set dependence has_many and belongs_to.

Sensor model

```
class Sensor < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible  :user_id, :data, :ids, :voltage, :status
    belongs_to :user
end
```

and User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sensors
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

In the new migration i created new column

```
class AddUserId < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :sensors, :user_id, :integer
    end
end
```

And Create method in the Sensor Controller

```
 def create

@sensor = Sensor.new(sensor_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @sensor.save
    format.html { redirect_to @sensor, notice: 'Sensor was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @sensor }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @sensor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

And when i press the create button,the dependence doesn't set

Comment: Your database and model set up looks right; it's probable that whatever code the create button is triggering is not correct. Can you paste the code that actually creates the model?

Comment: I edited the question adding Controller create method

Comment: Does your `sensor_params` include `user_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have `current_user` in your application.

SO in the create action, please try the following code.

```
def create
  @sensor = current_user.sensors.new(sensor_params)

  # YOUR CODE GOES HERE
end
```

Comment: Thx! it worked!  But when i relogin with other user , sensors list display all sensors, How can i do that sensors list display only current user's sensors ?  Sorry for my English)

Comment: In the index action of the SensorsController, use the line `@sensors = current_user.sensors` instead of `@sensors = Sensor.all` . If it will not work, please add your index action code.